# Could not found the path for create and write file

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-core, filestream, streamwriter

My code is
[image]
after run on Azure it say:

```
{
  "Message": "Cannot create 'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\DataFile' because a file or directory with the same name already exists."
}
```

how to resolve this??? My code tells it if the directory exists will be ignored and pass not created...why does it try to create and tell can not create because the directory exists???

Work in local work well...no error...the problem appears when run in azure

If I remove the code create a directory, It will error that the path does not exist and it doesn't create and write file...

[image]

In Azure

[image]

In Local
[image]

[image]

Comment: This code is in a context where the path does not exist, and it will create a file with this path.

Comment: the code may create a file if the file does not exist.. but if the directory itself doe not exist, it will not be created. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-io-streamwriter-ctor(system-string) so you need to verify if `D:\cn9\Project\PlayTogether\src\PlayTogether.Api\bin\Debug\net5.0\DataFile` this path really exist.

Comment: but will this code work when it is deployed to azure...

Comment: If the folder does not exist it will not work anywhere.

Comment: Are you there,...New problem ...help me....please...

Comment: If you need to always overwrite a previous file with that name, then you don't need to check if the file exists or not because the StreamWriter docs tells you that if the file exists it will be overwritten or created. Also _Directory.CreateDirectory_ internally checks if the directory exists or not so no check is necessary, just call _Directory.CreateDirectory_. Finally the error message tells us that you are trying to create a file with the name of the directory. Something is different from the code posted.

Comment: Let me edit it ...

Comment: Does my code have problem...

Comment: In Local this code work OK, but on azure, it goes problem: "Message": "Cannot create 'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\DataFile' because a file or directory with the same name already exists."

Comment: @Steve, I try to append but not overite the file,...and my code run in local it works OK, but when I deploy it into azure, it tells that: Cannot create 'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\DataFile' because a file or directory with the same name already exists.

Comment: I don't know why in local it works, but in azure, it does not work... Does someone have any idea???

Comment: It has been done, I fixed it, thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

This code work OK
In Azure it cause error be cause in D:\home\site\wwwroot\DataFile have a DataFile, it is a file,
I use the Kudu, (In App Service in Azure, search Advanced Tools)
[image]

then remove the file DataFile, then all things OK
[image]

Thanks all for support me!